# How to define $\mathrm{E}[X|Y]$ when $\mathrm{E}[X|Y=y]=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x \cdot P(X=x|Y=y) $

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We know that for $X$ and $Y$ being discrete RV, [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Computation) is:

$$\mathrm{E}[X|Y=y]=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x \cdot P(X=x|Y=y).  $$

How to define 
$$\mathrm{E}[X|Y]= ?? $$

Is it:  $$ \mathrm{E}[X|Y] \overset{\text{?}}{=} \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \Bigg[\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}x \cdot P(X=x|Y=y)\Bigg]P(Y=y).  $$

Comment: $E[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable and not a scalar (number), so the expression you propose is not it. For a very basic example: say that you do all calculations in $E[X\mid Y=y]$ and you find that $E[X\mid Y=y]=y^2$. Then $E[X\mid Y]= Y^2$.

Comment: Conditional expectation means expectation of $X$ given $Y=y$ where $y$ is arbitrary

Comment: Note that in the expression you give for $E[X|Y]$, the rhs is actually equal to $E[X]$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for such a useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$E[X|Y]=\sum_{y \in \mathcal Y}\Big[\sum_{x \in \mathcal X}x\cdot P(X=x|Y=y)\Big]\cdot \chi_y(Y),$$
where $\chi_y(Y)=1$ if $Y$ takes the value $y$ and zero otherwise. In that way, you indeed obtain a conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$ that is a RV.